# Split/gather pattern for jobs

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a set of jobs that I am trying to run in parallel.  I want to run each task on its own thread and gather the responses on the calling thread.

Some jobs may take much longer than others, so I'd like to start using each result as it comes in, and not have to wait for all jobs to complete.

Here is an attempt:

```
struct Container<T> {
    items : Vec<T>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    x: i32
}

impl Item {
    fn foo (&mut self) {
        self.x  += 1; //consider an expensive mutating computation
    }
}

fn main() {

    use std;
    use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};
    use std::collections::RingBuf;

    //set up a container with 2 items
    let mut item1 = Item { x: 0};
    let mut item2 = Item { x: 1};
    let container = Container { items: vec![item1, item2]};

    //set a gather system for our results
    let ringBuf = Arc::new(Mutex::new(RingBuf::<Item>::new()));

    //farm out each job to its own thread...
    for item in container.items {
        std::thread::Thread::spawn(|| {
            item.foo(); //job
            ringBuf.lock().unwrap().push_back(item); //push item back to caller
        });
    }

    loop {
        let rb = ringBuf.lock().unwrap();
        if rb.len() > 0 { //gather results as soon as they are available
            println!("{:?}",rb[0]);
            rb.pop_front();
        }
    }
}
```

For starters, this does not compile due to the impenetrable `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements` error.

What am I doing wrong and how do I do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple compounding issues, but the first one is a misuse / misunderstanding of `Arc`. You need to give each thread it's own copy of the `Arc`. `Arc` itself will make sure that changes are synchronized. The main changes were the addition of `.clone()` and the `move` keyword:

```
for item in container.items {
    let mrb = ringBuf.clone();

    std::thread::Thread::spawn(move || {
        item.foo(); //job
        mrb.lock().unwrap().push_back(item); //push item back to caller
    });
}
```

After changing this, you'll run into some simpler errors about forgotten `mut` qualifiers, and then you hit another problem - you are trying to send mutable references across threads. Your `for` loop will need to return `&mut Item` to call `foo`, but this doesn't match your `Vec`. Changing it, we can get to something that compiles:

```
for mut item in container.items.into_iter() {
    let mrb = ringBuf.clone();

    std::thread::Thread::spawn(move || {
        item.foo(); //job
        mrb.lock().unwrap().push_back(item); //push item back to caller
    });
}
```

Here, we consume the input vector, moving each of the `Item`s to the worker thread. Unfortunately, this hits the Playpen timeout, so there's probably some deeper issue.

All that being said, I'd highly recommend using [`channel`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html)s:

```
#![feature(std_misc)]

use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    x: i32
}

impl Item {
    fn foo(&mut self) { self.x += 1; }
}

fn main() {
    let items = vec![Item { x: 0 }, Item { x: 1 }];

    let rx = {
        let (tx, rx) = channel();

        for item in items.into_iter() {
            let my_tx = tx.clone();

            std::thread::Thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut item = item;
                item.foo();
                my_tx.send(item).unwrap();
            });
        }

        rx
    };

    for item in rx.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", item);
    }
}
```

This also times-out in the playpen, but works fine when compiled and run locally.